# Recursive query not working in ColdFusion 9

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, common-table-expression

This query when running in SQL server 2008 returns a bunch of results

```
WITH c 
AS
(
SELECT  deptid, reports_to_dept
FROM    glo_tree
WHERE   deptid = '#deptid#'
UNION ALL
SELECT  t.deptid, t.reports_to_dept
FROM    glo_tree T  
INNER JOIN c 
ON      t.deptid = c.reports_to_dept
)
SELECT deptid  
FROM c
```

However, when running in Cold Fusion 9 returns 0 records (no error whatsoever)

Interestingly, I've created a SQL function that runs the query then a stored procedure that executes the function, either one of them returns blank as well!

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[checkDept] (@deptid varchar(16))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    (
    WITH c 
    AS
    (
        SELECT  deptid, reports_to_dept
        FROM    glo_tree
        WHERE   deptid = @deptid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.deptid, t.reports_to_dept
    FROM    glo_tree T  
    INNER JOIN c 
    ON      t.deptid = c.reports_to_dept
)
SELECT deptid  
FROM c 
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getDept] (@deptid varchar(16))
AS
    SELECT deptid
    FROM dbo.checkDept(@deptid)
```

Then call them like

```
select * FROM checkDept('18538')

exec getDept @deptid='18538'
```

Both return nothing

Comment: Just a tip, you might want to include a length on your function parameter `@deptid varchar` should be `@deptid varchar(<something>)`. Since you aren't providing a length to that parameter - it doesn't use the full value you are passing in.

Comment: You accidentally enclosed the variable name in quotes, so the database is searching for the literal string "@deptid" - not the value *within* that variable. Remove them (and define the variable length as bluefeet suggested) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks bluefeet and Leigh, i've removed the quotes and added varchar values (same as the column definition). Still the same thing, returns nothing

Comment: (Edit) Did you run both statements in SQL Server directly (ie NOT using cfquery/cfstoredproc)? Hard to tell from the description..

Comment: Yes, i did, ran them both

Comment: So you are saying you *do* get results when you run `select * FROM checkDept('18538')` in SQL Server directly, but NOT when executed from CF?  That seems unlikely... Are you 100% positive you are running the *exact* same sql string in both? As a troubleshooting step, use the hard coded string (no CF variables) for now.

Comment: I think he said that he's getting zero records either way. There's a top to the tree at some point, but you're using an `INNER JOIN` all the way up. Eventually, there won't be anything to JOIN on and, since it's an INNER JOIN, the failure will propagate back and you'll get nothing. Try using a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: When i run the query in SQL manager, it returns something like 5 records (it's an up going tree, total number of possible levels is something like 11). Exactly the same query (copy and paste) in a function, stored procedure or ran as a Cold Fusion cfquery returns 0 records (no error whatsoever on any of them)

Comment: i don't know if it helps any, but when i run the same thing in Oracle, it works fine as Cold Fusion query:  WITH c AS
(
SELECT LEVEL AS lvl, deptid, reports_to_dept
FROM inventory.hr_tree_temp
START WITH deptid = '18538'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE deptid = prior reports_to_dept
order by lvl desc
) SELECT DISTINCT
    (SELECT MAX (lvl) FROM c) + 1 - lvl
    AS lvl, deptid, reports_to_dept
    FROM      c
    ORDER BY  lvl

Comment: It looks like a SQL server problem

Comment: Offhand, I do not see an obvious reason the exact same sql would return different results from CF, unless maybe your DSN is using pointing to a different version of the database than used in SSMS? Or perhaps your CF code is different than we are thinking. Hard to say without seeing the actual code. Run the basic SELECT. What does it return? 
SELECT  deptid, reports_to_dept
FROM    glo_tree
WHERE   deptid = '18538'` (Side note - is "dept_id" really a varchar column?)

Comment: *Hard to say without seeing the actual code.* BTW, the reason for saying that is the original CTE works fine with CF9+MSSQL 2005. So there is definitely something different on your end... Posting your exact cfquery will help rule out.